# Any way to overcome Cross-origin framing

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, google-hangouts

I am ultimately trying to load Google Hangouts into an Iframe, but it seems Google block any attempts to load their content into a frame, presumably for security reasons.

For example running:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

Displays nothing but gives the following message in the firefox web developer output:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.co.za/ does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Is there any way to overcome this?